# Return the number line a list of words is in?

Tags: string, list, python-3.x, indexing, text-files

I need help with a problem in which I create a function called index() which takes a file as a string and a list of words. The program will find the number lines that each word is in and return the number line next to the word.

So far my code reads as:

```
    f=open(file,'r')
    read = f.readlines()

    for word in lst:
        if word in range(len(read)):
            word[:]+1
    return read
```

I am pretty stuck here but I think you're supposed to search the index of the list of readlines(). For this problem I have to use for loops and format. Can anyone help me?

For FYI the return will look like this:

```
index('raven.txt',['raven','mortal','dying','ghost','ghastly','evil','demon])

ghost     9
dying     9
demon     122
evil      99, 106
ghastly   82
mortal    30
raven     44, 53, 55, 64, 78, 97, 104, 111, 118, 120
```

Also I am using python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(file, wordList):
    word_dict = dict()
    for word in wordList:
        word_dict[word] = list()
    with open(file,'r') as f:
         for lineNum, lines in enumerate(f,1):
             for word in wordList:
                 if word in lines:
                     word_dict[word].append(lineNum)
    return word_dict

myWordDict = index('raven.txt',['raven','mortal','dying','ghost','ghastly','evil','demon'])

for items in myWordDict:
    print(items, ":", myWordDict[items])
```

Is this what you wanted?